# Twitter Bootstrap 3 responsive table in modal doesn't scroll down on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a modal with a responsive-table in it and it works fine on a desktop computer, but on a mobile device it doesn't work great because you can't scroll to the end of the table.

You can see an example here: http://www.draftfantasyfootball.co.uk/players
If you click on a player name in the table, a modal opens up, but on a mobile device (or an iPhone 4 at least), you can't scroll to the bottom of the modal.

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know this too. If you have a modal with a table-responsive div on it, the page in the back scrolls down, not the modal.

Comment: This example requires you to make an account. Do you have an example you can show that does not require authentication?

Comment: Ah. At the time it didn't require an account. Sorry. I think the issue may have been fixed. Not sure

Comment: Could you please show us some code

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your modal on a mobile device is set to full width and height of the screen. If so, you should try to add the following property in your modal content class like as shown below:

```
.modal-content{
max-height: calc(100vh - 1px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It should work on default CSS,if it does not work then kindly show us your code.